# Accessing the Element API JSON

Tags: plugin-elementapi

I installed the Element API plugin and the `elementapi.php` file within the craft/config/ folder is set up just like the example on Github. I'm also trying to use this with a section called "news" like the example. However, when I try to access `news.json` I get a 404. Am I missing something? Do I need to call something in my templates to make that feed available?

Answer (score 1):

That plugin doesnt append any file extensions to the routes. Try either changing the route in `elementapi.php` to `news.json` or try to visit http://yoursite.dev/news

Comment: So are you saying that if I visit http://mysite.dev/news I should see the JSON coming through the network if I inspect the page? I have `news.json` as the endpoint in the `elementapi.php`

Comment: Hmm that should work... is there anything showing up? Do you get a 404 or just a white page? Could you post what you have in elementapi.php into your original question

Comment: Also worth checking the logs to see if anything is being logged when you hit that route.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old thread, but I stumbled onto it today because I was having a similar problem. I found that the source of my particular problem was due to the fact that I was also using Redirect plugin for Craft 3 on the site. The Redirect plugin appends a route to redirect everything to the 404 handler. I assume it was meant to be the last appended rule and to act as a default handler in the event no other route is matched. Unfortunately the element-api route got appended to the route rules array after that Redirect plugin default route, so the Craft routing never read the element-api route.

I deactivated the Redirect plugin and the element-api routing works now.